# Is there a way to do mirror Image mapping in EEVEE?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I need this option enabled to display some models properly.

[image: Blender 2.7 - Image Mapping]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to calculate mirroring UV coordinates by creating a sawtooth shaped graph.

[image: Desmos Graph]

Here is it implemented with nodes for cycles and EEVEE.
Since modulus is behaving in a different way below zero, the Fract operation is a better choice, but then we also need to scale the value to the 0 - 1 range.

[image: Implementation with nodes]

Comment: **surprised to see that it doesn't seem to work below zero** - the absolute node removes the negative values.

Comment: Nope, this is why: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls

Comment: @Anthony, please use a proper file service and remove the link to that horrible site.

Comment: @Anthony for sharing Blende files please prefer [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead

Comment: @Anthony, I have updated my answer so that it will work below zero, now there shouldn't be any problems to use it with your model.

Comment: No, I can't think of any way. To solve that you will need a true implementation of mirror Texture Wrapping.