# How to repeat an Image Map in blender 2.8

Tags: uv, node-editor

In Blender 2.79, there is a way to repeat images in a tab:

[image]

Whenever I try to apply this in Blender 2.8, in node form, I don't get the same results as mirror x and y in Internal. I know it is the Mapping node, but how do I get a repeating option like these examples:

Without the repeat

[image]

With the repeats

[image]

Here is the current node being used in EEVEE:

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add an image of your current nodes.

Comment: The image is added.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into this, seems like a lot of nodes for what was just a checkbox. Hopefully someone else has a better answer.
[Is there a way to do mirror Image mapping in EEVEE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142539/is-there-a-way-to-do-mirror-image-mapping-in-eevee)

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The "repeat" under the "flat" in the base color node is enough

Comment: You can see from the screenshots in the question that author was asking for *mirroring* of texture coordinates, not just *repeating*